# How do I properly delete a record from a droplist in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table called faculty in my database. I made a dropdown from where I can visualize the names of the faculties. I tried to also make a button to delete the current selected element. But all it does, is changing the selected item to another one and not actually deleting the faculty from the database. I am new to PHP, a bit of help ?

```html
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT name, faculty_id FROM faculty ORDER BY name ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
    ?>

    <select name="categories">
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['faculty_id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
            $row = $row['faculty_id'];
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['delete_faculty'])) {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM faculty WHERE faculty_id = $row";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }
    ?>
    <form action="admin" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="delete_faculty">Delete</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Use the Jquery to remove the option and the same time send the Ajax request to PHP to delete the record in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT name, faculty_id FROM faculty ORDER BY name ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
        ?>
       <form action="#" method="post">
        <select name="categories">
            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['faculty_id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                $row = $row['faculty_id'];
            }
            ?>
        </select>
            <input type="submit" name="delete_faculty" value="Delete">
        </form>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['delete_faculty'])) {
            $cato = $_POST['categories'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM faculty WHERE faculty_id = $cato";

            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            header("Refresh:0");
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: This works as I wanted. One more thing though.. after  I delete a faculty, i have to refresh the page to see the result in the dropdown. How can I fix this ?

Comment: I added my code `header("Refresh:0");` by using this it wil refresh your page after it runs the query

Comment: "after I delete a faculty, i have to refresh the page": you are already reloading the page is you are handling the POST request. Simply put the part where you delete the row before the part where you write the select control, i.e. switch the order of the two PHP blocks.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to use the proper row ID in your `delete` query. That should do the trick:

```
$facultyId = (int)$_POST['delete_faculty'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM faculty WHERE faculty_id = " . $facultyId;
```

Additionally, you should have a look at prepared statements. They'll help you to avoid SQL injections